# search by name and array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, if-statement

Hello I'm trying to do a searchbar that can search a name(string) and tags(array). But I dont rteally know how to write the if statement. This is how I want it to look like. Any ideas on how to make it work?

(lamp.name is a string, the filter for it is working
lamp.Kkeywords is an array with tag names for the lamps this is the part I dont know how to write.)

```
async loadLamp() {
    let lamps = await http.get('/data/lamps');
    lamps = lamps.data;

    for (let lamp of lamps) {
        let lampName = lamp.name;
        let lampKeyWords = lamp.keywords
        if (!lampName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchLamp)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!lampKeyWords.find(function(this.searchLamp) {
            return this.searchLamp;
        })){
            continue;
        }
        lamp = new Lampa(lamp.name, lamp.id, lamp.description, lamp.cost, lamp.image, lamp.keywords, this.basketModal);
        lamp.selector = this.elem.find('.lampor');
        this.lamps.push(lamp);
        lamp.render();
    }
}

search() {
    this.searchLamp = this.elem.find('#search').val();
    $('.product').hide();
    this.loadLamp();

}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example. What does the `lamp` object contain?

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: The parameter in your find function will be a keyword from the keywords array.  Within that function you should return true if the keyword matches the input (however you check that).